# Modify Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API via Attribute Usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My goal is to have a controller with method

I am trying to create an attribute `DefaultValue` as below:

```
class ModelClass
{
  int modelId;

  string modelName;

  [DefaultValue("foo")]
  string modelString;
}

class ModelClass2
{
  string fooBar;

  [DefaultValue("bar")]
  string otherStringValue;
}
```

with controller:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(ModelClass model)
{
...
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(ModelClass2 model2)
{
...
}
```

The way this `DefaultValue` will work is that when a user passes a value in, if `modelString` in `ModelClass` is null or the empty string, this will populate it with `"foo"` (from the constructor of the attribute).
Else, the user defined value will be used.
The same would be true of `otherStringValue` in `ModelClass2`

In ASP.NET MVC it looks like this can be accomplished by using the `BindProperty` method of a `IModelBinder` interface, but I can't find anything similar for WebApi

Comment: Documentation - [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Based on what I've read in the documentation, there doesn't seem to be any way to handle what I am trying to do - the properties are populated without context for what attributes are applied to them, or the entire model is populated and I can't just fill in the one property I care about

Comment: Using Model Binders you could. It just requires a little more work.

Comment: Based on my reading of the documentation and examples I've found online, Model Binders need to be applied at the level of the entire ModelClass / ModelClass2 - is there a way to apply it just to the one property within that class?

Comment: The binder would inspect the model instance and type and populate as needed based on your custom attribute. You are in control of how it does that. This extensibility point allows you to do just that.

Comment: In the documentation linked, it seems that a single model binder must populate all fields of the associated model - is this not the case? If not, how do I signal to continue using other model binders for the remaining properties?